# Error: undefined method `deprecation_warning' for Thor:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, controller, version

When I generate controller with command "rails generate controller page index" and I had this error, ruby 2.3.3p222, rails:Rails 3.2.22

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem with this gem (thor) and it occurred after updating your version. For this version of Ruby I installed thor 0.20.3 and rails should work normally again.